# What is the sum of $\arctan\frac{1}{2r^2}$

Tags: trigonometry

What is the sum of $\arctan\frac{1}{2r^2}$ with $r$ going from $1$ to $\infty$ ?

I know this has to be reduced as a telescoping sum. Just cant quite do it. Just need a hint.

Answer (score 0):

It can be written as $$\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{(2r+1) -(2r-1)}{1+4r^2-1}\right)$$